# How to use fortran libraries like lapack, odepack in linux

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack

I am new to fortran and linux. I wish to learn using external libraries like lapack, odepack and all. On internet searches, I can find the downloadable files, source codes and .sh files but have no idea on how to integrate those things as external libraries and call them in gnuplot. I need some references on usage of these packages, detailed, starting from how to integrate those using makefile like stuffs as external libraries using terminal commands and use them in fortran programs.

Comment: Linux distributions come with packages for lapack, I recommend you to use those. Google for "name of distribution linux install lapack". Then, you add the `-llapack` flags on linking and that's it. This has nothing to do with gnuplot though. You won't find "tutorial like" help on stackoverflow, see the help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Advice: do a diligent search yourself, try what you find, and report with detailed questions describing your attempt and the error that you are trying to solve.

Comment: You can also check out the Intel Parallel Studio which automatically comes with Intel Math Kernel Library, which includes BLAS, LAPACK, ScaLAPACK, sparse solvers, fast Fourier transforms, and vector math. Intel website has massive documentation and examples. If you are a student, teacher, open-source developer, Intel parallel studio is free for you.